# Помогите разобраться с заданием

Tags: c++, шаблоны-проектирования

Вообщем вот задание

Составить программу, которая будет
записывать контейнер целых чисел в файл (текстовый или бинарный)
читать целые числа из файла (текстового или бинарного) в контейнер
Запись контейнера в файл (`template method`) должен содержать последовательность следующих операций
открытие файла
запись чисел
закрытие файла
Метод считывания (`template method`) из файла должен содержать последовательность следующих операций
открытие файла
Считывания чисел и добавления их в контейнер
закрытие файла
Использовать паттерн Шаблонный метод.

Тут проблема в том что запись и чтение 2 разные типа(`ofstream` и `fstream`).И если в интерфейсе сделать один метод то потом при наследовании нельзя будет выбрать ofstream или ifstream а если сделать методы разные то тогда толку от этого паттерна.
Вот код:

```
 class Base
{
virtual void open(ofstream &a) = 0;
virtual void doing(array<int, 6>::iterator it, ofstream &a) = 0;
void close(ofstream &a) 
{ 
    a.close();
}
public:
void execute( array<int, 6>::iterator it, ofstream &a)
{
    open(a);
    doing(it,a);
    close(a);
}
};
class Writer:public Base
{
virtual void open(ofstream &a)
{
    a.open("FIle.bin", ios::binary);
    if (!a)
        cout << "Error\n";
}
virtual void doing( array<int, 6>::iterator it, ofstream &a)
{
    a.write((char*)&it, sizeof(it));
}
};
class Reader:public Base
{
virtual void open(ofstream &a)
{
    a.open("FIle.bin", ios::binary);
    if (!a)
        cout << "Error\n";
}
virtual void doing(array<int, 6>::iterator it, ofstream &a)
{
    a.read((char*)&it, sizeof(it));
}
};
void main()
{
array<int, 6> ll {0,1,2,3,4,5};
Base *arr[]{ &Writer(),&Reader() };
ofstream f1;
ifstream f2;
arr[1]->execute(ll.begin(),f2);
arr[0]->execute(ll.begin(), f1);
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    cout << ll[i]<<"  ";
cout << "\n\n";
}
```

Comment: Отредактируёте ваш код с ошибками и добавьте его сюда, тогда вероятность ответа на ваш вопрос возрастёт.

Comment: @IlonMask обновил

Comment: используйте ссылки на [std::fstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream) вместо ссылок на std::ofstream, в качестве аргументов функций. Во второй строке функции `main` у вас пара висячих указателей.

Comment: @acade Что значит висячих указателей?

Comment: @Hadler2, вы берете адресс временного объекта. `&Writer()` - объект создается, запоминается его адресс,  и объект уничтожается, а взятый адресс (указатель в массиве `arr`) будет указывать на уже не существующий объект.

Comment: @acade я переделал ссылки.Компилируется но файл не открывается и не создается

Comment: @Hadler2, `f1` и `f2` в функции `main` тоже `std::fstream`?

Comment: @acade да файл уже открывается но туда ничего не записывается и не читается

Comment: @Hadler2, в методе `open` в классе `Writer` измените флаг `ios::binary` на `ios::binary | ios::out`, а в классе `Reader` на `ios::binary | ios::in`

Comment: @acade запись работает чтение нет

Answer (score 0):

Так как реализация метода `doing` может выполнять как запись так и чтение передача ссылки на `std::ofstream` не годится. Стандартная библиотека предоставляет класс `std::fstream`, который является слиянием `std::ifstream` и `std::ofstream`, то что нужно.

Далее, семантика методов `doing` (из `Writer`-а):

```
a.write((char*)&it, sizeof(it));
```

Этот код не выполняет то, что вы предполагаете. Вы берете адресс итератора `it`, что не имеет никакого отношения к данным, на которые указывает итератор. Нужно записывать не адресс итератора, а данные, которые он хранит.

Итератор это хорошо, но вам нужна работа с последовательностью. Должен быть передан итератор на начало и на конец последовательности.

Т.к. `std::fstream` работает как с потоками ввода, так и с потоками вывода, вам необходимо явно указывать для каких целей открывается поток: для ввода (`std::ios::in`) или для вывода (`std::ios::out`).

---

```
Base *arr[]{ &Writer(),&Reader() };
```

В данном отрезке кода: создается объект типа `Writer` (все сказанное также относится к `Reader`). Выполняется операция взятия адресса, адресс записывается в массив `arr` и затем объект, адресс которого мы запомнили уничтожается. В результате получим висячий указатель.

Один из возможных корректных вариантов:

```
Writer writer{};
Reader reader{};
Base* arr[] = { &writer, &reader };
```

---

Корректная реализация:

**Base class**

```
class Base
{
    virtual void open(std::fstream &a) = 0;

    virtual void doing(array<int, 6>::iterator first, // итератор на начало
        array<int, 6>::iterator last, // итератор на конец
        std::fstream& stream          // ссылка на поток
    ) = 0;

    void close(std::fstream &a)
    {
        a.close();
    }
public:
    // те же изменения
    void execute(array<int, 6>::iterator first,
        array<int, 6>::iterator last,
        std::fstream &a)
    {
        open(a);
        doing(first, last, a);
        close(a);
    }
};
```

**Writer class**

```
class Writer : public Base
{
    virtual void open(std::fstream &a) override
    {
        a.open("FIle.bin", ios::binary | std::ios::out);
        if (!a)
            cout << "Error\n";
    }
    virtual void doing(array<int, 6>::iterator first,
        array<int, 6>::iterator last, std::fstream& stream) override
    {
        // проверка на доступность потока
        // проверка на валидность итераторов
        for (; first != last; ++first)
        {
            // получаем указатель на реальные данные которые хранит итератор
            const char* pointer_to_data = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&*first);
            // записываем эти данные
            // sizeof(int), sizeof(*first),
            // sizeof(std::array<int, 6>::value_type) : как угодно
            stream.write(pointer_to_data, sizeof(*first));
        }
    }
};
```

**Reader class**

```
class Reader : public Base
{
    virtual void open(std::fstream &a) override
    {
        a.open("FIle.bin", ios::binary | ios::in);
        if (!a)
            cout << "Error\n";
    }
    virtual void doing(array<int, 6>::iterator first,
        array<int, 6>::iterator last, std::fstream& stream) override
    {
        // проверка на доступность потока
        // проверка на валидность итераторов
        for (; first != last; ++first)
        {
            // проверка активен ли поток и может ли быть произведено чтение
            // получаем указатель на место памяти, куда указывает итератор
            char* pointer_to_data = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&*first);
            stream.read(pointer_to_data, sizeof(*first));
        }
    }
};
```

Еще, в вашем примере, вы сначала производите операцию чтения, а затем операцию записи. Проверить за один заход работу можно следующим образом:

```
int main()
{

    Reader reader{};
    Writer writer{};
    std::fstream stream{}; // кстати, достаточно одного потока fstream

    std::array<int, 6> arr1{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    std::array<int, 6> arr2;

    std::cout << "arr1 до записи, (arr2 пустой): \n";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
        std::cout << arr1[i] << "\t";
    std::cout << "\n";

    // записываем данные из arr1
    writer.execute(arr1.begin(), arr1.end(), stream);
    // читаем данные в arr2
    reader.execute(arr2.begin(), arr2.end(), stream);

    std::cout << "arr2 после чтения: \n";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
        std::cout << arr2[i] << "\t";
    std::cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

---

Стоит заметить, что данное решение очень негибкое.
По-хорошему, в файл предварительно необходимо записать количество элементов.
Но т.к. решение (по-видимому) используеться в образовательных целях, этими моментами можно пренебречь.